# Linear Algebra Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T:P2->P2 be a linear transformation and A be the matrix of the linear transformation. Prove that if det(A) does not equal 0 then T is one-to-one.

I know that for T to be 1-1 then the kernel is a zero vector and therefore A would reduce to an identity matrix I'm just not sure how to tie that into the determinant?

Comment: Perhaps you can show that both conditions are equivalent to $T$ being invertible?

Answer (score 0):

You must know that $\det(A)\neq0$ is equivalent to $A$ being invertible. In turn, you must know that this is equivalent to the statement
$$
Av=0\iff v=0.
$$
Those are two standard equivalences, that you may want to prove if you did not know them.

*Note:* In fact if the matrix representation of $T$ is invertible, then $T$ is a *bijection*.